# How to shift the close button in the toolbar to the left

Tags: android, toolbar, menuitem, android-toolbar, android-menu

I am working on this app. And using a transparent toolbar. I have added menu items on it.

As shown in the image

[image]

**Now how should I shift the close button in the toolbar to the left side.**

Here is the code

**MainActivity.java**

```
transparent_toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_play_screen);
```

**menu_play_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item

    android:id="@+id/action_back"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_playQueue"
    android:orderInCategory="99"
    android:title="Add to queue"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_queue_music_white_24dp"
    />

</menu>
```

Comment: Don't add it to the menu, it always aligns right. Add it as a button inside the toolbar layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with a menu.xml. If you want the button to be on the left you need a custom layout for your toolbar, something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/close_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/close_button"
            android:text="@string/close" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Then inflate the rest of your menu in the toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

I dont't think you'll be able to do it with the help of menu. But you have several options:

1. Use the navigation button. First, set your custom [navigation icon](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setNavigationIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)), then set the [navigation listener to listen for click event](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setNavigationOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)).
2. Toolbar is a [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html), so you may add any views to it.

Personally, I think the first option is more logical, because the "close" button has the navigation purpose. Moreover, you may want to [set your toolbar as an app bar](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) to integrate it with your fragment/activity.